# c++ std::function type cheking correct?

Tags: c++, std-function

I wish to use std::function type from  so that function signature is checked on assignment. But I fail to understand what is happening in this case

```
//g++  5.4.0
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
int f(int x)      { std::cout << "//f:int->int\n";    return x; }
int g(double x)   { std::cout << "//g:double->int\n"; return 1; }
int main()
{
    std::function<int(int)> fct;
    fct = f; fct(1);
    fct = g; fct(1);
}
//trace
//
//f:int->int
//g:double->int
```

The behavior for f is what I want, but I thought that "fct=g;" would cause a compile time error.

Any light on this case please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::function` is flexible and uses `type erasure` underneath, so if you have `std::function` object with with signature `std::function<R(Args...)>`, it will accept any `Callable` that can be called with type `Args...` and returns type `R`,

So in your case for `std::function<int(int)>`,  function of type `int g(double);` can be called with type `int` arguments compiler will just promote `int` to `double`,

If you run this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
int f(int x)      { std::cout << x << " " << "//f:int->int\n";    return x; }
int g(double x)   { std::cout << x << " " << "//g:double->int\n"; return 1; }
int main()
{
    std::function<int(int)> fct;
    fct = f; fct(1);
    fct = g; fct(2.5);
}
```

You can see that `fct` will only accept `int` and afterwards compiler promote it to `double`, So In the output of `fct(2.5);` it will print `2 //g:double->int` and not `2.5 //g:double->int`

Comment: thanks @gaurav . if I understand you correctly, maybe f shoud be int->double, g should be double->double, and fct should be int ->double. So fct=g "forces" the first parameter to be cast to int (testing it does confirm, but I not 100% sure, since in your exemple g returns an int.. )

Comment: @chetzacoalt, return types shouldn't make difference the code above since each of them are `int`, and yes when code calls `fct(2.5)`, since `fct::operator()` only accepts `int`,  it converts 2.5 to 2.

Answer (score 2):

`std::function` accepts any callable that where the parameters can be converted and the return type is convertible. If they aren't you get a compilation error. For instance:

```
int h(double& x);

std::function<int(int)> fct;
fct = h; // <- compiler error
```

Answer (score 0):

to complete the answer from @gaurav, complete scenarii using implicit conversion (it did surprise me, so I add it for anyone interested)

```
//g++  5.4.0
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class C{ 
    public : 
    int i; 
    C(int _i) : i(_i)  { std::cout << "//C::C(int " << i << ")\n"; } 
};
class D{ 
    public : 
    int i; 
    D(int _i) : i(_i)  { std::cout << "//D::D(int " << i << ")\n"; }
    D(C c)    : i(c.i) { std::cout << "//implicit conversion D::D(C " << c.i << ")\n"; }
};

int f(C c)   { std::cout << "//f:C->int : "; return c.i; }
int g(D d)   { std::cout << "//g:D->int : "; return d.i; }

int main()
{
    {
        std::cout << "//--- test implicit conversion\n";
        C c(1); 
        D d(2);
        d=c;
    }
    {
        std::function<int(C)> fct; C c(1); D d(2);
        std::cout << "//direct calls\n";
        std::cout <<   f(c) << "\n";
        // std::cout << "//" <<   f(d) << "\n";  // no conversion D->C provided by class C -->> error: could not convert ‘d’ from ‘D’ to ‘C’
        std::cout <<   g(d) << "\n";         
        std::cout <<   g(c) << "\n";             // implicit conversion, then g:D->int
    }
    {
        std::cout << "//case function:C->int\n";
        std::function<int(C)> fct; C c(1); D d(2);
        fct = f; std::cout << "//" << fct(c) << "\n";
        //std::cout << "//" << fct(d) << "\n";   // no conversion D->C provided by class C -->> error: could not convert ‘d’ from ‘D’ to ‘C’
        fct = g; std::cout << "//" << fct(c) << "\n";
        //std::cout << "//" << fct(d) << "\n";   // no conversion D->C provided by class C -->> no match for call to ‘(std::function<int(C)>) (D&)’
    }
    {
        std::cout << "//appels via function : D -> int\n";
        std::function<int(D)> fct; C c(1); D d(2);
        //fct = f;    // conversion D->C would be meaningless to f
                      // -->> error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::function<int(D)>’ and ‘int(C)’)
        fct = g; std::cout << "//" << fct(d) << "\n";
        std::cout << "//" << fct(c) << "\n";      // implicit conversion, then g:D->int
    }
}

//trace
//
//--- test implicit conversion
//C::C(int 1)
//D::D(int 2)
//implicit conversion D::D(C 1)
//C::C(int 1)
//D::D(int 2)
//direct calls
//f:C->int : 1
//g:D->int : 2
//implicit conversion D::D(C 1)
//g:D->int : 1
//case function:C->int
//C::C(int 1)
//D::D(int 2)
//f:C->int : //1
//implicit conversion D::D(C 1)
//g:D->int : //1
//appels via function : D -> int
//C::C(int 1)
//D::D(int 2)
//g:D->int : //2
//implicit conversion D::D(C 1)
//g:D->int : //1
```